# Modify global variable array through a bash function, passing the function the name of the variable as a string

Tags: arrays, bash, function, multidimensional-array, declare

Dear I need something to help me in this. I'm trying to modify a global array through a function , using an auxiliary variable called "array". I would like to modify the global array "config " using a function that takes a string with the name of the variable " config".

I'm trying the following but I have not gotten results .

```
declare -A config

function testABC {
    array=${1}[@]
    array["key"]="value1"
    array["key2"]="value2"
}

testABC "config"
echo ${config["key"]}
echo ${config["key2"]}

#desired output:
#value1
#value2
```

**My version of bash is 4.2.45**

regards.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf -v` to set the value. This avoids an unsafe use of `eval`, as `printf` can *only* print text into a named variable, nothing more.

```
testABC () {
    printf -v "$1[key]" '%s' value1
    printf -v "$1[key2]" '%s' value2
}
```

Be sure to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 (from which this answer is taken) for a good understanding of the drawbacks of the various approaches. Shell languages simply aren't a good fit for this type of programming.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right, something like this should work:

```
function testABC {
  array="$1"
  # Don't proceed unless the argument is a valid identifier
  valid_id="^[[:alpha:]_][[:word:]]+$"
  [[ $array =~ $valid_id ]] || return

  eval "$array"["key"]="value1"
  eval "$array"["key2"]="value2"
}
```

We store the argument passed to the function in array variable. After that we construct line that assigns values to keys and use `eval`. `eval` replaces `$array` with `"config"` and executes the whole line, assigning the values properly.

Comment: Don't use `eval` without knowing that `$1` is *just* the name of an array. You're allowing `testABC` to execute arbitrary code passed as an argument.